# ¿Cómo puedo declarar una función lambda como argumento en una función?

Tags: python

```
def map2_mio(lambda,l1,l2):
listaDef= [];
for x in l1:
    for y in l2:
        var = lambda;
        listaDef.append(var);
return listaDef;
```

Tengo este código qu ehe hecho en el cuál me dicen esto: *Dada un par de listas (de la misma longitud) y una función de dos argumentos, devolver la lista de los resultados de aplicar la función a cada par de elementos que ocupan la misma posición en las listas de entrada* , el cuál tiene que ser con estos argumentos de ejemplos:

```
map2_mio((lambda x,y: x+y) ,[1,2,3,4],[5,2,7,9])
```

## Salida esperada: [6, 4, 10, 13]

¿Cómo puedo declarar una función lambda en mis argumentos de la funcion def map2_mio? ¿O no se declara como función lambda como yo lo tengo puesto?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunos problemas en tu código, pero estabas cerca de la respuesta.

- En línea `var = lambda` supongo que quieres obtener en `var` el resultado de ejecutar la función sobre dos valores de la lista. Pero no estás ejecutando la función, ya que para ejecutarla hay que usar paréntesis y pasarle los parámetros. Es decir, buscabas algo como `var = lambda(x,y)`
- Pero hay un error de lógica. Ya que has hecho los bucles *anidados*, para cada iteración del más externo se completa un bucle completo del más interno. Es decir, para cada valor de `x`, se pasa por todos los valores de `y`.

  Esto no es lo que tienes que hacer. Si por ejemplo una lista contiene `[1,2]`  y la otra contiene `[3,4]`, lo que se te pide es que ejecutes `lambda` sobre las parejas `(1,3)` y `(2,4)`, en cambio tus bucles anidados recorrerían las parejas `(1,3)`, `(1,4)`, `(2,3)`, `(2,4)`.
- No deberías usar `lambda` como nombre de un parámetro, pues ese nombre ya tiene otro significado en Python. Llamémosle por ejemplo `f` por ser una función.
- Te sobran todos los punto y coma ;-)

De estos cuatro, el problema más complicado es el segundo. No tenemos que recorrer las dos listas de forma *anidada*, sino *en paralelo*, avanzando por ambas *a la vez*.

Para esto tienes dos formas.

Una forma es utilizar una variable índice (por ejemplo `i`) que comienza en cero y va avanzando de uno en uno, hasta que una de las listas termina, y en cada iteración accedes a `l1[i]`, `l2[i]`. Esta solución será así:

```
def map2_mio(f, l1, l2):
    listaDef = []
    i = 0
    while i<len(l1) and i<len(l2):
        var = f(l1[i], l2[i])
        listaDef.append(var)
        i = i + 1
    return listaDef
```

Una variación de este mismo esquema es quedarse con la longitud de la lista más corta, e iterar `i` entre 0 y ese valor. Esto te permite usar un `for` en lugar de un `while`:

```
def map2_mio(f, l1, l2):
    listaDef = []
    longitud = min(len(l1), len(l2))
    for i in range(longitud):
        var = f(l1[i], l2[i])
        listaDef.append(var)
    return listaDef
```

El otro enfoque es hacer uso de la función `zip()` que viene de serie con Python. Esta función recibe varios argumentos que han de ser iterables, y va iterando en paralelo por todos ellos a la vez, hasta que el más corto de todos ellos se termine. En cada iteración te devuelve una tupla formada por elementos sacados de cada uno de los iterables. Es decir, justo lo que necesitas. Esto te evita iterar por los índices y te permite iterar directamente por los valores, lo que es más *pythónico*:

```
def map2_mio(f, l1, l2):
    listaDef = []
    for dato1, dato2 in zip(l1, l2):
        var = f(dato1, dato2)
        listaDef.append(var)
    return listaDef
```

Haciendo uso de *list comprehensions* puede quedar todo mucho más compacto, pero en esencia es equivalente a la implementación anterior:

```
def map2_mio(f, l1, l2):
    return [ f(dato1, dato2) for dato1, dato2 in zip(l1, l2) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
def example(a,b):
   return [sum(x) for x in zip(a,b)]

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,2,7,9]

print(example(a,b))
```

**explicacion:**

1. hacemos un bucle `for` tipo `shorthand`
2. la funcion `zip` agrupa 2 arreglos
3. la funcion `sum()` suma 2 valores

Comment: No me queda claro

Comment: @RoyalUp Porque esta respuesta en realidad no responde lo que preguntas... Sólo muestra cómo aplicar una suma a los elementos, pero no cómo aplicar una función arbitraria que le puedas pasar como parámetro...

Answer (score 2):

Puede ser algo como:

```
def map2_mio(function, list_a, list_b):
    list_c = [function(list_a[i], list_b[i]) for i in range(len(list_a))]
    return list_c

function = lambda x, y: x + y
map2_mio(function, [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 2, 7, 9]))
```

Usando zip como en el comentario anterior, tambien podrías hacer:

```
def map2_mio2(function, list_a, list_b):
    list_c = [function(i, j) for i, j in zip(list_a, list_b)]
    return list_c

function = lambda x, y: x + y
map2_mio(function, [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 2, 7, 9]))
```

Habría que validar que las listas sean de igual tamaño.